# Use of "however" and "yet" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

Consider this scenario

> A can help B. However, A is limited by Z, yet he can help B by ...

Sorry if the example is very abstract. But I guess you got my meaning.

Can *however* and *yet* be used in one sentence? "However" wants to bring an exception to the previous sentence, while "Yet" tries to say that this exception is not so rigid.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that both 'however' and 'yet' are somewhat redundant - but the real cause is you are repeating 'A[he] can help B'. Fix that and the other problem disappears, e.g.

> A is limited by Z, but can help B by ...